# Can not send request after switching to Https?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-web-api, https

I have a project with 2 assemblies: one WebUI and the other one is WebAPI.

I have a html form in web project in which it sends request to web api. In web api config file, I registered my web site and no cors problem occurs.

Every thing was fine until i switched my site to https.

now all my jquery is not sending any request to web api.whats more in WebApiConfig files I registered my https web site too.
All jquery request are blocked with this error:

[image]

And Also all jquery files that request to web api are inside https site and are not external.

Comment: change your api to https

Comment: @madalin ivascu jquery is inside my own project. i didnt refrence any external Js file!

Comment: the url from your ajax man change it to https

Comment: @madalin ivascu my sub domain is not on https, I get response with fiddler. but not whithin https site